# How can I compare multiple properties of two lists of objects and return a new list of matching items?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to compare two lists of objects in C# and return a new list that contains only the items that match certain criteria. Each list contains objects with the following structure:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

I want to compare the `Name` and `Value` properties of each object in both lists, and return a new list of objects that meet the following criteria:

- The Name property of the object in `list1` is equal to the Name
  property of the object in `list2`.
- The Value property of the object in `list1` is greater than the Value
  property of the object in `list2`.

I have tried using LINQ's Where method and Join clauses, but I am having trouble getting the desired results. Here is the code I have so far:

```
var results = list1.Where(x => x.Name == list2.Where(y => y.Name).FirstOrDefault() &&
                               x.Value > list2.Where(y => y.Value).FirstOrDefault());
```

This code is only returning a list of the first object in list1 that meets the criteria, rather than a list of all matching objects. Can you help me understand what is going wrong and suggest a solution to get the desired results?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: can you try this : `var results = list1.Where(x => list2.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name && y.Value < x.Value)).ToList();`

Comment: `join` or `intersect` with custom comparer

Comment: Are the lists sharing the objects? or are the instances different but same content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a `Join` to match the `name` between `list1` and `list2`, then filtering for greater `value` with a `Where`, finally selecting the unique (distinct) items from `list1`?

```
void Main()
{
    var list1 = new List<MyObject> { 
        new MyObject { Name = "A", Value = 2 },
        new MyObject { Name = "A", Value = 1 },
        new MyObject { Name = "B", Value = 1 } 
    };

    var list2 = new List<MyObject> {
        new MyObject { Name = "A", Value = 2 },
        new MyObject { Name = "A", Value = 1 },
        new MyObject { Name = "C", Value = 1 }
    };

    var result = list1
        .Join(list2, l1 => l1.Name, l2 => l2.Name, (l1, l2) => new {l1, l2})
        .Where(x => x.l1.Value > x.l2.Value)
        .Select(x => x.l1)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();

    result.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine($"Name:{r.Name} Value:{r.Value} IsActive:{r.IsActive}"));
    
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

This returns items from `list1` with `name` matches in `list2` where the `value` of `list1` is greater than the `value` in `list2`:

> Name:A Value:2 IsActive:False

Comment: what is the expected result if you replace `2` by `3` in the first line for `list1`?

Comment: @MohammedSajid That is a good question. I think you might want to add `.Distinct()` after the `Select` clause to make sure only unique values of `list1` are returned. I've updated my post above to reflect that.